# Facebook FB.api - just use the JSON object it sends back?

Tags: jquery, json, facebook

So taking a look at the API doc page here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api

I'm wondering if the response received back is an HttpResponse or a JSON object.  They say that they return a JSON object in the response.

So since they are performing things such as response.name, etc. does it mean we don't need to parse the JSON object?  I don't get it.  I was going to use the jQuery parseJSON to parse the returned JSON object so I could traverse through it and grab the data.

UPDATED:

Ok well here's my actual code:

```
var uri = "/" + userID + "/albums";

    FB.api(uri, function (response) {
        // check for a valid response
        if (!response || response.error)
        {
            alert("error occured");
            return;
        }


        alert("console.log(response): " + console.log(response));
        alert("response: " + response[0].length);
});
```

the uri being passed in is this: `/1637262814/albums`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a JavaScript value back. [Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/) always returns an object, but some [old methods](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/) return numbers or booleans. Usually this is an object like `{ name: 'My Name', id: 1234 }`. Easiest to run this in firebug: `FB.api('/me', function(r) { console.log(r) })` as it will let you explore the response. You can also take a look at this example: http://fbrell.com/fb.api/user-info.

Comment: well it's supposed to return a JSON object.  Problem is no matter how many times I try to alert something out whether I try response[0] or whatever it may be I just keep getting "object" in the alert box.  I don't know how to grab the JSON string so I can parse through it using jQuery's getJSON.  I just need the string.  But I don't understand why in their JS SDK examples they are showing response.name, etc.  is that a php parsing thing that enables them to straight up reference the name of the value they're trying to work with?

Comment: When I alert out the reponse[0] I get an undefined error but I know the response is not null

Comment: Ok console.log says response is undefined.  But if that's the case then why did it enter my callback and pass this check:          if (!response || response.error) {
            alert("error occured");
            return;
        }

Comment: I did notice in firebug in the console this:    Object { data=} so maybe there is a response string coming back but no data?

Comment: It's likely you don't have the required [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) to access albums. Here's an example: http://fbrell.com/fb.api/photo-albums.

Comment: Yea, I switched up to using the FB.login and rolling with my own button.  Added the request for permissions.  I was wondering though instead of sending /me/ I should be able to send the userid /userid/albums?access_token=..." as the uri correct/.  Or don't I need to specify the access_token because the SDK can pick that up from the cookie automatically?

Comment: this fbrell is nice but I don't get who made this and where the examples are stemming from.  I mean I can log in but where is this code that's there coming from and how would I be able to see other types of syntax using the API like this?  how would one know to type in photo-albums, what is this site?

Answer (score 1):

So they are just returning a JSON string, but your programming language wraps that into an HttpResponse. you have to extract the JSON string from the response and then parse it.

Comment: If that's the case then why can't I do alert(response[0]); to see that string?  when I do this, I just get 'object' as the value.  So is the JSON string the only object in the response?

Comment: Looks like I'm getting no data back: { data=}

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be impolite, but I think the fastest way to find this out would be to just try and **alert(response)**, and/or **alert(eval(response))** and see what happens.

Just **alert(response)** should be enough to let you know what you're getting and how to treat it.

Comment: Did that already.  When I do an alert response it just says it's an object.

Comment: actually it's undefined which makes sense cause I'm still getting back no data.  The problem still remains even after the user has granted me the permission set I need to get at their albums and photos.